# Checking to which range a value belongs in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have some data in the following way

| Category | [Range 1_min] | [Range 1_max] | [Range 2_min] | [Range 2_max] | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 120 | 130 |  |  | ... |
| B | 100 | 119 | 131 | 140 | ... |

I want to be able to quickly query a number and have it return the category it belongs to, for example 135 belongs to B and 121 belongs to A.

I already have a script that does this, but since there are 1000+ categories, it takes a long time to run. Is there a faster way of doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `LOOKUP`:

```
=ArrayFormula(LOOKUP(2,1/((G2>=B2:B)*(G2<=C2:C)+(G2>=D2:D)*(G2<=E2:E)),A2:A))
```

[image]

**Addition:**

For more ranges you can add `MMULT` (not sure it's easier):

```
=ArrayFormula(LOOKUP(1,5/(MMULT(--(K2>={B2:B,D2:D,F2:F,H2:H}),ROW(A1:A4)^0)*MMULT(--(K2<={C2:C,E2:E,G2:G,I2:I}),ROW(A1:A4)^0)),A2:A))
```

some conditions:

1. change first argument of `LOOKUP` to `1`
2. for second `LOOKUP` argument change denominator to `5` (number of cols to compare + 1)
3. for second `MMULT` argument `ROW(A1:A4)` use row count according column count to compare (i.e. for 4 cols ->`ROW(A1:A4)`, for 6 cols -> `ROW(A1:A6)` etc. )

Comment: Thanks, I have a question though, why is the search_key 2 in the LOOKUP function? And is there a way to generalize it to more than 2 ranges (other than the naive `+ (G2>=X2:X)*(G2<=Y2:Y)` for example)?

Comment: @JoseAngelCazares search_key = 2 ensures that the lookup from the array ```1/(((G2>=B2:B)...)``` will return the last position for a number equal to or less than 2. I add an option with a more ranges to the answer.